# JavaFX building borderPane with FXML files

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, borderpane

Using a `BorderPane` layout, can you populate each part of it (top, left, center, right and bottom) using separate FXML files?

So I would have a main.fxml like:

```
<BorderPane fx:controller="main.mainController"  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" >

    <top>
        reads from top.fxml
    </top>

    <left>
        reads from left.fxml
    </left>

    <center>
        reads from center.fxml
    </center>

    <right>
        reads from right.fxml
    </right>

    <bottom>
        reads from bottom.fxml
    </bottom>

</BorderPane>
```

Comment: See if `fx:include` works from here -> https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do it:

## add it in java

After you load the `BorderPane`, you can load other FXML files and put them into the `BorderPane`.

E.g.

```
BorderPane root=FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("root.fxml");//maybe this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("root.fxml"), depending on project structure
AnchorPane center=FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getResource("center.fxml");//maybe this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("center.fxml"), depending on project structure
root.setCenter(center);
stage.setScene(new Scene(root));
```

## inside FXML

As @[Sedrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2423906/sedrick) points out in the comments, you can also use [fx:include](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.fxml/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#include_elements):

```
<center>
    <fx:include source="center.fxml"/>
</center>
```

In both options, it works the same with `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right`.